# SQS communication with services

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, amazon-sqs, messagebroker

I’m trying to learn more about Microservices and in specific AWS SQS and I’m not sure if the way I’m picturing the architecture is correct. Wondering if someone here could help.

How SQS works in terms of communication between two services? Say I have a client application that calls userService that needs to get some data from productService before sending the response back to the client side.

How SQS would work in this case? userService would need to send a message and start listening for the response? Are there blocking concerns about this?
Would it be the right approach? If not, what’s the suggestion for a use case like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Queues are not a good fit for such service orchestration scenarios. Look at the [Cadence Workflow](https://cadenceworkflow.io/) that supports such long running operations natively.

Answer (score 1):

SQS is a queue service. Simple Queue Service. As the name suggest, It aims to be simple

You would need to understand [what is a queue](https://aws.amazon.com/message-queue/) and [why do we need queues / when it is needed](https://aws.amazon.com/message-queue/benefits/)

Overally, your use case and the question is a little bit too broad but I will try to incoporate a simple one

Example :

- You have a service that run a report generation for a few thousand users
- You have another service to get all products / orders associated for that user.
- You can create a operation that will push the these users into your queue. This is the producer
- You have a queue of something like this [User_1],[User_2],[User_3]...[User1000]
- You can configure some machines that actively look at the queue and takes the messages. They are the consumers
- Each consumer take the message and process it locally ( Gather all products/ orders related to the user) . Maybe email the result eventually
- SQS is a good candidate for a queue service that is simple, fast and scalable enough